# Finding Min Distance From Start Node to Other Nodes in DFS Tree and Their Back Edges

Tags: graph-algorithm, tree-traversal

The problem is this:

1. Find DFS and compute distance from start node to each of the other
   nodes in the graph, assign each of the nodes v their distance from start node
2. Next find the min of each of the nodes v with the distance found earlier and the distance for some back-edge connecting a descendant u of v with some w

Doing the first part is easy, first just run BFS on the DFS.

The second part seems harder. What is the best way to find the distance for back edges?

Is this problem possible to be done in O(n+m) even with computing the DFS?

Answer (score 1):

1. To find the distance from the source node, you need to run BFS from the start node(s), You will get the distance of nodes(v, such that v is reachable from s). No need to run DFS for this problem.
2. This problem is not clear to me. If you want to find the distance of back edge from source node (Let's define the distance of back edge : distance of the node u, such that (u,v) is a back edge), You need to run DFS from source node and check if any edge is a back edge and if so return the distance of that node using the precomputed distance in previous step(BFS run).
   To check if an edge is back edge or not in DFS, you need to have three states of nodes (rather than just two - visited or non-visited). lets use three colors for them- WHITE, GRAY and BLACK. WHITE- not seen yet, GRAY - seen but still under DFS exploration, BLACK - DFS exploration done from that node.
   So in this version of DFS, if you find a GRAY node, then that edge which takes you to the GRAY node is back edge.
   Hope it helps.
   Please look at Coreman version of DFS algorithm for reference.